Make the draft save changes in real time
I just wrote out an answer on Math Stack Exchange for like an hour and at some point the page randomly reloaded, I don’t know if my finger accidentally hit something or if this is a bug, but it’s happened another time recently too. When the page reloads, only some of the text was automatically saved - like, perhaps 75% of what I had written.
For some reason I lost motivation and decided to not rewrite it and the answer was unpostable in that incomplete form.
Can someone please ensure that auto-text saving is occurring ideally after every character you type in real time, or something close to that?
Thank you.
This was on an iPhone 15 in Safari running iOS 18.

The site software periodically saves drafts of posts that are being written or edited, but that data loss was caused by your browser doing a refresh. It may have done that because of memory paging.

I agree that it's annoying. When writing big answers on my phone, I try to remember to regularly copy the answer to the clipboard, so I don't get bitten by a random refresh.

Better not count on a website, no matter which, to save things for you. Best would be to write it somewhere else, e.g. Notes which you know for sure will not be lost, then when ready copy and paste it.
